# Mongoose / Mongo find in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In MongoDB/Mongoose i have a Server collection which got this element ...

```
  owners: [{

    type: String,
    ref: 'User'

  }]
```

The owners array contains many id linked to an User collection. Very simple. It populates correctly and everything.

In a Server.find() i must retrieve the list of servers that got a specific owner. So the correct query would be something like

```
      FIND IN SERVER WHERE (OWNERS ARRAY) CONTAINS (THIS ID)
```

Which i translated in Mongoose as ...

```
      Server.find({'owners.$': user._id}).exec(function(error, servers) {

        console.log(servers);

      });
```

I was thinking "owners.$" let us search through a collection-array and in this case compare it with user._id but I was wrong, it seems the ".$" can only be used in a ".update()" query.

How can you do the same for a find ? What is the equivalent ? I'm searching everywhere and can't find out the solution ...

Thank you people ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making it more complicated than it needs to be as you can directly filter on array properties just as you would a normal property:

```js
Server.find({owners: user._id}).exec(function(error, servers) {
    console.log(servers);
});
```

Comment: How my god ! Thank you that was so simple I didn't even try ! :)